# newHeads: does logsBloom contain all addresses?

Tags: blocks, logs, bloom-filter

Looking at [newHeads](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/pubsub#newHeads) and the docs say:

> Fires a notification each time a new header is appended to the chain, including chain reorganizations. Users can use the bloom filter to determine if the block contains logs that are interested to them.

The response body includes `logsBloom`; does that filter include *all* addresses in the block or just addresses included in logs from smart contracts?

Answer (score 0):

`logsBloom` is part of the [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) generated from the events fired in the block.

The bitarray `logsBloom` is used to determine if is possible that an event were triggered in the block, so information is stored directly, it is just that some bits are turned on when an event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Blooms do not work with eth transactions (purely sending eth), eth transactions do not emit logs so do not exist in the bloom filter.